# List of things to check to prevent VC++ applications from showing fatal error message boxes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, error-handling

Every now and then there's a strong need to write a program in such a way that it never (really never) shows an error message as a message box. For example it can be a program run inside a daily build - if it hangs with a message box the daily build hangs.

Unfortunately VC++ runtime has a lot of ways to trigger message boxes when indicating errors.

First of all, whenever an exception is not handled `terminate()` is called which calls `abort()` which causes "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way." message box. This can be worked around by catching all exceptions and/or using `set_terminate()` to set a custom `terminate()` handler without message boxes.

Then, whenever an exception escapes any destrutor during stack unwinding `terminate()` is also called. `set_terminate()` helps here as well.

Then, there's a "pure virtual function call" message box that is shown in some hardcore cases of mismatching the number of functions expected by the caller and those implemented by the callee. `_set_purecall_handler()` should help here.

What else to do to a VC++ program to be absolutely positively sure it doesn't show a message box in some fatal situation?

Comment: The two things you describe are programming errors. It seems better to me not to make them, or at least to have them detected by code reviews et al, rather than apply a band aid.

Comment: @Neil: Yes, sure, but it's totally inconvenient to have daily builds hung. Like you come on Monday expecting to see results of three daily builds - from Saturday to Monday - and see none. You log onto the build server just to see one of those message boxes. Seeing three failure reports with a message logged in them would be much better.

Comment: @Neil: Not to mention, you might want to add some kind of an error log or a dump of the stack trace in the case of exceptions, instead of your users getting an ugly message box indicating an error which you won't be able to properly investigate.

Comment: A more mainstream example would be code that runs as a service and doesn't even have a desktop to show the message on.

Comment: Surely fielding errors sensibly is what every well-written application should do? My objection is the idea you can graft this stuff on afterwards - it should be part of the original design.

Comment: +1 to Neil. Spend your effort making your program not crash, instead of spending effort trying to hide your program crashing. You're only hurting yourself in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you use a helper program to launch it and have this helper limit the time your program can run. This is by far the safest way if you can do it, as it handles every case. Some things you cannot handle in your program directly, such as "This program is not a valid Win32 application" which might happen if you are missing a DLL.

Answer (score 2):

Hook the MessageBox API before daily build.

BTW, i think [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634%28VS.85%29.aspx). is a relevant API.

Comment: and _set_invalid_parameter_handler.

Answer (score 2):

- [`_set_error_mode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sas1dkb2.aspx)
- Make sure you compile with `/EHa` so that SEH errors such as acess violation will be cought by `catch(...)`
- surround your code your own SEH filter using `__try {} __except {}`
- [`_CrtSetReportMode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y71x448.aspx)
- [`_RTC_SetErrorFunc()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dc6szt1x%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- [`_set_invalid_parameter_handler()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9yf33zb%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- [`_set_new_handler()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a45x8asx%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- [`_set_se_translator()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z4bw5h5%28VS.80%29.aspx) is a possible option to translate SEH exceptions to C++ exceptions
- [`set_unexpected()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h46t5b69%28VS.80%29.aspx)